# How I prevent rapid clicking at next Click because its effect the calculation of the slider

Tags: jquery, slider

When I click normally on next icon it work perfectly but when start clicking rapidly at next icon calculation not behave as like normal behavior.

```
 [jsfiddle]   https://jsfiddle.net/karanbhilware/0wfa2zcs/1/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can effectively 'cap' the frequency of which a user can click your controls.

Try something like this at the top of your click handlers:

```
// If the element has the disabled class, don't execute any more of the function.
if($('.zw-nw-recNewsNext').hasClass('disabled'))
    return;

// Add disabled class on click, then remove after half a second.
$('.zw-nw-recNewsNext').addClass('disabled');
setTimeout(function(){ $('.zw-nw-recNewsNext').removeClass('disabled'); }, 500);
```

So you can set a disabled class on the button on click, then after a specific interval of time (500ms here), you can remove the disabled class. Now when clicking the button, the user can only advance forward/ backward if the button element doesn't have the disabled class applied to it.

Another way is to use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead of CSS transitions to style your UL - using animate you'll have access to a callback function. So you can set the disabled class (as above) but remove it as soon as the animation is complete.

This is a cleaner solution, as you can more accurately control when the button should or should not be clickable, rather than setting a specific value (500ms in my example).

Comment: Thanks its working actually I not friendly with animate() function that's why I am not using :(